# Display latest 10 galleries

Tags: gallery

I want to create a custom page that will display let's say 20 latest galleries / page - but only the first image from the gallery, not all of them. something like this: http://www.autoblog.it/gallerie/

I've done this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'post_parent' => $postid,
'numberposts' => 1,
'paged' => $paged,
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    echo the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false, false, true )
    echo get_the_title();   }
}?>
```

it works but what it does is to display latest 10 images, not latest 10 galleries, so first image from each gallery.

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Getting the latest posts with a gallery is simple: search for posts with the string `'[gallery'`.

```
$posts = get_posts(
    array (
        's'           => '[gallery'
    )
);
```

Getting the first image from each gallery is harder, because you have to render the `gallery` shortcode. I would not use the default handler, it does much more than we need here. It would waste too much time.

Step by step …

### The main function

Let’s start with a function to retrieve a list of latest gallery posts with two parameters: the number of posts and a formatting helper:

```
function t5_list_galleries( $num = 10, $formatter = 't5_gallery_list_formatter' )
{
    $posts = get_posts(
        array (
            's'           => '[gallery',
            'numberposts' => (int) $num
        )
    );

    if ( ! $posts )
        return FALSE;

    $list = new T5_Gallery_Image_Extractor( $posts );

    $html = call_user_func( $formatter, $list->get_results() );
    return $html;
}
```

As you can see we need a class `T5_Gallery_Image_Extractor` to build the list and a formatting function to create the Markup. I haven’t put the formatter into the gallery extractor to stay flexible: You might use the function in a widget or in a shortcode with different formatters.

### The class T5_Gallery_Image_Extractor

The class constructor expects a list of posts. It doesn’t care about how we got that list, so we can build is manually with a completely different main function.

Internally, it replaces the default shortcode handler for `gallery` with a simplified version to get just the first image from the first gallery in a post.

The public method `get_results()` returns an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://single.wp/blog/gallery-2/
            [img] => <img width="150" height="150" src="http://content.wp/singlewp/uploads/2013/01/git-bash-150x150.png" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="git-bash" />
            [title] => Gallery 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://single.wp/blog/gallery-1/
            [img] => <img width="150" height="150" src="http://content.wp/singlewp/uploads/2013/01/hat-150x150.png" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="hat" />
            [title] => Gallery 1
        )
)
```

So we get the post URL, the image markup and the post title for each post with a gallery.

The code, sorry, no time for comments, maybelater. :)

```
class T5_Gallery_Image_Extractor
{
    protected $results             = array ();

    protected $current_post        = NULL;

    protected $old_gallery_handler = FALSE;

    public function __construct( $posts )
    {
        $this->replace_gallery_shortcode();

        foreach ( $posts as $post )
            $this->collect_first_image( $post );
    }

    public function get_results()
    {
        remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );

        if ( $this->old_gallery_handler )
            add_shortcode( 'gallery', $this->old_gallery_handler );

        return $this->results;
    }

    protected function collect_first_image( $post )
    {
        $this->current_post = $post;
        do_shortcode( $post->post_content );
        $this->current_post = NULL;
    }

    protected function replace_gallery_shortcode()
    {
        // replace the old gallery shortcode
        if ( isset( $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags']['gallery'] ) )
            $this->old_gallery_handler = $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags']['gallery'];

        remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
        add_shortcode( 'gallery', array ( $this, 'gallery_shortcode' ) );
    }

    public function gallery_shortcode( $attr )
    {
        static $processed_posts = array ();

        $post = $this->current_post;

        if ( in_array( $post->ID, $processed_posts) )
            return; // no need to run through all galleries of a post.

        $processed_posts[] = $post->ID;

        if ( ! empty ( $attr['ids'] ) )
        {
            if ( empty ( $attr['orderby'] ) )
                $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';

            $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
        }

        if ( isset ( $attr['orderby'] ) )
        {
            $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
            if ( ! $attr['orderby'] )
                unset( $attr['orderby'] );
        }


        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
            'id'         => $post->ID,
            'include'    => '',
            'exclude'    => ''
        ), $attr));

        $id = intval($id);

        if ( 'RAND' == $order )
            $orderby = 'none';

        $att_args = array (
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'order'          => $order,
            'orderby'        => $orderby,
            'numberposts'    => 1
        );

        if ( ! empty ( $include ) )
        {
            $att_args['include'] = $include;
            $attachments         = get_posts( $att_args );
        }
        else
        {
            $att_args['post_parent'] = $post->ID;

            if ( ! empty ( $exclude ) )
                $att_args['exclude'] = $exclude;

            $attachments = get_children( $att_args );
        }
        $this->results[] = array (
            'url'   => get_permalink( $post->ID ),
            'img'   => wp_get_attachment_image( current( $attachments )->ID ),
            'title' => $post_title = esc_attr( $post->post_title )
        );
    }
}
```

### The formatter

Dead simple: just convert the array from above into a HTML list.

```
function t5_gallery_list_formatter( $list )
{
    $output = '<ul class="t5-gallery-list">';

    foreach ( $list as $item )
        $output .= sprintf(
            '<li><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></li>',
            $item['url'],
            $item['title'],
            $item['img']
        );

    return "$output</ul>";
}
```

Now we can use the main function wherever we need it:

```
print t5_list_galleries();
```

And the result is a nice list of the latest ten posts with a gallery, the first image from the first gallery is used as link text.

[image]

Visual formatting is left to the stylesheet:

```
.t5-gallery-list {
    /* here be dragon rules */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thank you for the code...

I also made a shorter code that acually works ,,

here it is:

```
<?php
wp_reset_query();
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results
("
 SELECT *
 FROM $wpdb->posts 
 WHERE
   post_status = 'publish'
   AND
    ID IN (
SELECT DISTINCT post_parent
FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE
  post_parent > 0
AND
  post_type = 'attachment'
AND
  post_mime_type IN ('image/jpeg', 'image/png')
  )
   ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
 ");

  foreach($posts as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
<div>
```

```
 </span>
 <div class="slider-image">
   <?php
   $images = get_children(array(
  'post_parent' => get_the_id(),
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'orderby' => 'ID',
  'order' => 'ASC'
));
$ids = array_keys($images);
?>

<div style="height:180px; width:150px; border-bottom:solid 1px #f17d0b; float:left; margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-top:20px; overflow:hidden;" ><?php 
echo the_attachment_link($ids[0],false, false, true);

  ?><div style=" font-size:11px; color:#666; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">             <?php echo get_the_title();    ?> </div></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php
  endforeach;
 wp_reset_query();
 ?>
```

This actually work perfect. The only question is now how can i do pagination ???

Thank you very much.

Comment: This will list the latest attachments, not the latest galleries. A gallery is a part of a post, not an attachment.